# ¿Cómo evitar que se envíe un formulario presionando enter usando taginput?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estoy usando la biblioteca de entrada de etiquetas de Bootstrap, pero no puedo evitar enviar el formulario al presionar Enter. Al presionar enter, el cursor debe permanecer en ese mismo campo. He utilizado varios códigos pero sin éxito.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
     </div>
      <input type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control form-control-md" data- 
      role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" value="" onkeydown="pulse(event)" required>
</div>

   <script>/* No funciona*/
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach( node => 
 node.addEventListener('keypress', 
  e => {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
    }
}))
```

});

```
  <script>/* No funciona*/
  function pulse(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('prevented');
   return false;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Para *deshabilitar en envío automático del formulario* cuando se pulsa ***ENTER***, puedes añadir un `button[type="submit"]` desabilitado y oculto al principio del formulario que capture y detenga el evento. Ahora tendrás que pulsar el botón de envío que tengas al efecto o gestionarlo mediante javascript.

Este método *no requiere javascript*, el código que uso es:

```
<form ...>
    <button type="submit" disabled class="none" aria-hidden="true"></button>
```

donde la clase `none` equivale a `display:none`, usa la equivalente de *bootstrap*. O se puede añadir el atributo `hidden`:

```
<form ...>
    <button type="submit" disabled hidden aria-hidden="true"></button>
```